# husky simulation installation, but there is an error about joystick

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-noetic, husky, joystick

I installed the husky simulation desktop as follows (refer to the clearpath website):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-husky-simulator ros-noetic-husky-desktop
```

then, when I type in:

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch
```

there is an error, and gazebo can not start.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Please do not use images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text and format as code.

Comment: FYI, your gazebo image was not being displayed, so I edited your post to fix it. Your title question is about the joystick message, so that's what I answered. But I don't believe that message will have any affect on the startup of gazebo.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many different problems which can cause gazebo to not startup. 1) Did you `source /usr/share/gazebo-11/setup.bash`? 2) As a test, can you successfully start gazebo with an empty world: `gazebo --verbose /usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world`?

Answer (score 1):

The log message "Error: couldn't open joystick" is not a serious problem and you can safely ignore the message.

As an enhancement, you can configure a real usb or bluetooth port for a real playstation game controller if you want to.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my first time asking a question. Actually, the Gazebo environment can not run, so i can not simulate. I would like to use Gazebo and Rviz to verify robot navigation in my own laptop( ubuntu20.04 and ros noetic)